# React delete item component via button deletes items in list after that item too

Tags: reactjs

Please help! Not sure what's wrong with my code below. I'm trying to only delete child component after the delete API call returns but somehow all items after the item to delete also get removed from list. Luckily the delete API call only gets hit once for the correct item.

`
import "./styles.css";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <TopList />
  );
}

function TopList() {

  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      "id": "something1",
      "title": "something1"
    },
    {
      "id": "something2",
      "title": "something2"
    },
    {
      "id": "something3",
      "title": "something3"
    }
  ]);

  const onHandleDelete = (itemDelete) => {
    setList(list.filter(item => item !== itemDelete))
  }

  return <div>
      {list.map(item => <ListItem item={item} onDelete={() => onHandleDelete(item)} />)}
    </div>
}

function ListItem({item, onDelete}) {
  const [deleteClicked, setDeleteClicked] = useState(false)

  const onClickDelete = () => {
    !deleteClicked && setDeleteClicked(true);
    // Do delete API call
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Also check API call finished
    if(deleteClicked) {
      onDelete();
    }
  }, [deleteClicked, onDelete])
 
  return <div>{item.title} <button onClick={onClickDelete}>Delete</button></div>
}
```

`

Expecting only the item that had the delete button clicked should be removed from item list.

I've also tried adding a key (generated from item properties) to the components but that didn't seem to work either. Maybe I added in wrong places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `key={item.id}` to your `<ListItem` in the `map`. And it is better to compare id than the whole object in your `filter`

Comment: Right. I tried adding `key` to `ListItem` but it didn't work so I deleted it. It still deleted that item and the items on the rest of the array. I think it has something to do with `useState` being reserved for that position(?). For example, when I added some logs and clicked to delete item 2, item 3's state also gets updated with deleteClicked=true after item 2 gets removed from the list.

Comment: Have you tried to change your `filter` to `setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== itemDelete.id))` like here : https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-elion-xy3epv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh my god. That's what I was missing. Thanks! It looks like I added needed to add both the `key` on `ListItem` and do the filter based on that `key` and then it will work. Do you know why that is the case just for improving my understanding of react?